# Having an issue with VS add-in loading in primary copy of VS

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I am testing out an add-in created by someone else and set the add-in application debug properties to:

Start external program: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

/resetaddin Microsoft.VSAddin.Addin1

Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\

After I changed the addin definition file path to point to the bin/addin.dll I ran it and it worked fine in the experimental copy of visual studio. I ended up closing both copies of visual studio a couple minutes later and now when I open my primary copy it automatically loads this add-in even though I am not debugging it anymore. So this means I can't edit the addin now since this addin is always in use. Any ideas why it is installed into my main copy of vs now and why I can't get it loaded in the experimental copy?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the folling settings to deploy only under Experimental instance:

First copy the `.Addin` file from

**C:\Users[xyz]\Documents\Visual Studio 20[ij]\Addins\**

to the

**C:\Users[xyz]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio[kl].0Exp\Addins\**

folder.

Then you should add the */RootSuffix Exp* switch to start the exp. intances instead of the normal one with debug. You can change the extension of the original `.Addin` while you are developing/testing the Add-In.